# bootstrap v3.0.3 css in ie version 8 or more

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am using  Bootstrap v3.0.3 css in my project .
Those styles are  applying in moz,chrome and safari except ie 8 or more.
what to do .
Any help is appreciated
Thanks .

Comment: Please read the Bootstrap Docs for IE8 information: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: yup ..got it.madi it worked just by including html5shiv and respond js ..thanks for those